# Jquery keypress() event doesn't catch Tab keycode

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to do something if users press tab while they are typing on a textbox. But the code below can't handle tab button. I tried "13" for "Enter" and it worked but I'm not sure why it didn't work for Tab.

I think it might be because of the textbox losing focus when tab pressed. If this is the case, how can I prevent lossing focus when people press tab in this textbox?

Thank you.

```
$("#tagInpKey").keypress(function (e) {
    if (e.which == 9) {
       alert("Tab Pressed");
    }
});
```

Comment: Use `keydown` event instead.

Comment: @Mohammad Is there a way I can prevent lossing focus?

Comment: The answer posted by @RoryMcCrossan does not lose focus so should resolve your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/):

> The keypress event is sent to an element when the browser registers keyboard input. This is similar to the keydown event, **except that modifier and non-printing keys such as Shift, Esc, and delete trigger keydown events but not keypress events**.

To fix this, use `keydown` instead:

```
$("#tagInpKey").keydown(function (e) {
    if (e.which == 9) {
       alert("Tab Pressed");
    }
});
```